# Application exe icon not displayed ... because it is in a dll

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, prism

My application is build in C#4, using Prism (CAL) and WPF.

We have the application (the .exe).

The splash screen and the icon are in a .dll that serves as the branding dll. So, we have different dll for different branding flavor of our application.

The problem is the following:

- When pinning the EXE on the task bar, the icon is the generic one from MFC (and not the one in the branding dll)
- When accessing the EXE from the start menu, the problem is the same.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Regard,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the icon property of the shortcut to something like "C:\blah\my.dll". This can be done manually or through your MSI packaging software.